# downloading multiple audio files in a loop failed (python)

Tags: python, loops, amazon-polly

I;m trying to download mp3 files from AWS polly (text to speech service) using a loop in python
The codes I used is as follows:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    filename = str(i) + ".mp3"
    response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(VoiceId='Joanna',
                OutputFormat='mp3', 
                Text = "blah blah blah"
    file = open(filename, 'wb')
    file.write(response['AudioStream'].read())
    file.close()
```

this ended up giving me files with 1kb which means there's nothing in each files..
What can I do to improve the code so that the loop pauses until each audio file is downloaded completely..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this work as expected if you do it for a single file, outside of any loop?

Comment: yes it works fine

Comment: i believe I need to use subprocess... but I don't know how..

Comment: Hmm I don't think you need `subprocess`. I don't have a AWS credentials, otherwise I'd try it myself, but just from looking at the documentation it looks like `response["AudioStream"]` is a `botocore.response.StreamingBody` object, which represents a live, asynchronous socket connection over which data can be streamed. Your loop goes so fast that the socket is closed practically as soon as it has a chance to first start reading. It seems like there exist these special `waiter` objects, which await asynchronous processes - not sure how they work, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: There is also a chance you can set a custom `InvocationType` keyword-parameter for the `synthesize_speech` method. Changing it from `Event` to `RequestResponse` has the effect of changing some asynchronous functions to synchronous ones, but again, I don't know much about AWS.

Comment: thank you for your advice.. I thought the same but I'm kind of new to python and AWS.. so I couldn't find this 'waiter' object you are talking about...  I found another way. I used command and subprocess instead of dealing it directly in Python.. It worked. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/get-started-what-next.html) from Amazon. It demonstrates the use of `with closing(...)` to ensure proper closing of the response stream.

Here is some code, untested, that should work for you:

```
from contextlib import closing

for i in range(3):
    filename = f'{i}.mp3'
    response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(VoiceId='Joanna',
                OutputFormat='mp3', 
                Text = "blah blah blah"
    if 'AudioStream' in response:
        with closing(response['AudioStream']) as stream, open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            while data := stream.read():
                file.write(data)
    else:
        print(f'Problem streaming audio: {response=}')
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work either.. this case resulted in 0kb in all three files.

Comment: However, I found another way. I used command and subprocess instead of dealing it directly in Python.. It worked. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @JohnLee: I think that you should have explored the documentation further. Using subprocess is not a good way to process the files. The problem is basically that your code does not read to completion the returned streams - a single read operation could result in only 1K of data. You should loop over the stream until you read 0 bytes.

Comment: @JohnLee: I've updated my answer to loop over the stream data until it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem but in a little bit different way..

As I have guessed, using subprocess function may have been the key..

Using command(aws command line) in a subprocess resulted in good mp3 files.

codes are as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
import codecs

for i in range (0,3):
    word = 'blah blah blah'
    file_name = '0' + str(i) + '.mp3'
    print(word)
    
    command = 'aws polly synthesize-speech --text-type ssml --output-format "mp3" --voice-id "Salli" --text "<speak>' + word + '</speak>" ' + file_name
    print(command)
    

        
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```